# Как выделить внешний IP пользователю OpenVPN?

Tags: сеть, ip, vpn, openvpn

Здравствуйте. Есть машина, которой выделено 2 ip адреса, положим 34.34.34.34 и 34.34.34.35
Как, используя OpenVPN выделить клиенту IP 34.34.34.35? Т.е. чтобы на компьютере клиента при подключении был указан именно этот, внешний IP, а не вытуренный, например, 10.4.0.4

Comment: P.S. Машина на GNU/Linux

Comment: Если не знаешь способа - это не значит что его нет. Но тем не менее никак.

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге Опенвпна. Там на каждый отедльный ип создайете новый конфиг в папке с конфигами.

```
ip34.conf
ip35.conf
```

И так далее имено могут быть любые главное чтоб они лежали в папке с конфигами ОпенВпн и имели коректный синтаксис внешний ип задаеться как раз внутри конфига.Само названия не имеет особой разницы.